# Ajax is not working in server but works fine in local host

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax call is not working in entire site. But works fine in `localhost`. I cannot able to debug this issues.

I have used ajax entire website. I totally fed up.

Anyone please help me to fix this bug!!

One of my Sample Ajax Code:

```
function advanced_addTopic(cid) {    
  $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/checkSubtopicStatus.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: {'cid':cid}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields 
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
              if(data==="True"){
                $("#subtopicDiv").html($("#subtopicDiv"+cid).html());
                $("#advanced_testid").val(cid);

                var hiddenCourse=$("#createTest").attr('class');
                $("#courseHidden").val(hiddenCourse);
                $("#advanced_addquestionModal").modal('show');
                $("#subtopic").focus();
                $("#question").focus();
                var tempVal=$("#getID").text(); 
                $("#advanced_courseHidden").val(cid);
                } else {
                  alert("Create subtopics to insert questions!");
                }

        }
 });
```

My PHP Code is here:

```
<?php 
        class loginValidation {  

             function validate() 
             {
                ob_start();
                session_start();
                include "../../connection.php"; 
                $id=$_POST['cid'];

                $query = mysql_query("select * from advanced_subtopic where testid='$id'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
                        echo "True";    
                 } 
                else {
                        echo "False";
                }
            }
        }
        $loginValidation=new loginValidation;
        $loginValidation->validate();?>
```

[My Concosole Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM3ky.jpg)

[CONSOLE RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQwBA.jpg)

Comment: check console for the error and let us know the error also

Comment: **1.** Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. **2.** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO. Specially since you're not even escaping user inputs at all.

Comment: It returns -False @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Try jQuery is working or not..

Comment: Is the request sent from the browser? Do  you have the same web-server and setup on localhost and the server? Is the request in access logs on the server? Do you get anything in the error log on the server? Do you have the same php version and packages on the server? Maybe you have PHP7 where ´mysql_´ functions are removed?

Comment: But few Pages are working with this code @MagnusEriksson

Comment: jquery is working -@MickeyPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
(data==="True")
```

we should code like

```
($.trim(data)=="True")
```

Should trim the data to avoid unwanted space.

Problem solved.